# bounded stack implementation

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I'm new to Java.
I would like to create a bounded stack where a user can choose in the constructor how many elements he wants in his array (stack). My Stack is an array of objects.
I created something like this:

```
public class BoundedStack {

    int Size;
    java.lang.Object[] List;

    public BoundedStack(int size) {

  this.Size = size;
}
```

It would be cool if I create an instance of the class BoundedStack, an array of the type object would be created with the size of the Paramater in the constructor. (`int size`).

If the user doens't want to give in a number in the constructor and just declares an instance of the class `BoundedStack`. The List array should have a default value of 32 elements.

Something is just not working over here. Do i have to use 2 constructors ? one with the parameter and one without ? I know the constructors are not that hard to code...But something is passin' my mind by instantiating the sizes and the array...

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue ?

Comment: If you want the size parameter to be optional then yes, you need to write one constructor with the parameter and one without. The rest of your question, I didn't understand.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, two constructors. One should take a size argument; the other should take no arguments, and should defer to the other using `this(32);` to get a default size of 32.

By the way, `LinkedBlockingDeque` would be the way of implementing this using standard JDK classes.

Also, you might want to change terminology. Usually *capacity* would be the word for the maximum number of elements the stack can hold, and *size* would be the number of elements currently on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need two constructors. One constructor with no parameters, and one with a parameter for the size:

```
public BoundedStack() {
    // you could set the array directly
    list = new Object[32];

    // however, it's better to call the other constructor using the this() syntax
    this(32);
}

public BoundedStack(int size) {
    list = new Object[size];
}
```

You don't need to track the size of the array separate from the array itself. You can simply use `list.length` to find the size of the array, in other words:

```
public int getSize() {
    return list.length;
}
```

Side comments: you don't need to say `java.lang.Object` you can simply use `Object`. Also by convention you should not start variable names with upper case letters.

Comment: Thanx so much! I also had a problem of creating that list with the size object. You've helped me now by showing an example! peace bro

Comment: You should definitely take the second option of invoking `this(32)` rather than creating the array directly. It looks fine at the moment, but when you start adding more code into the constructor, it'll get unmaintainable to keep duplicating the code.

Comment: Agreed, just trying to tailor the answer to the level of the question, which is why I mentioned both.

Answer (score 1):

> Do i have to use 2 constructors ? one with the paramater and one without ?

You don't have to do it that way, but that seems the most natural.  For example:

```
    ...

    public static final int DEFAULT_BOUND = 32;

    private final Object[] elements;
    private int size;

    public BoundedStack() { this(DEFAULT_BOUND); }

    public BoundedStack(int bound) {
        // validate bound ...
        elements = new Object[bound];
        size = 0;
    }

    public int size() { return size; }

    public int getBound() { return elements.length; }
```

The other thing that is confusing you (I think) is that a *bounded* stack has at least two "sizes":

- One "size" is the number of elements *currently* in the stack.  If you are going to be consistent with the `Collection` framework, then that size should be called `size`, and it should be returned by a getter with the non-standard name `size()`.
- The second "size" is the bound; i.e. the maximum number of elements that you will allow to be in the stack.  I'd recommend you call this the `bound` or `upperBound`, and that you provide a conventionally named getter for it.
- There is also possibly a third "size", representing the amount of space *currently allocated* to the bounded stack.  However, that should probably be internal; i.e. not exposed via a getter.

In the collection framework, the term "capacity" is used for an initial "sizing parameter".  However, collections types that have a "capacity" parameter only treat it as a hint.  What you want is a hard limit on the stack size, and (IMO) that warrants the use of a *different* name.

You should be scrupulous in your API and internals to distinguish between these two "sizes" ... or you will confuse the people using the API, and ultimately, yourself.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're saying about "capacity", but I'd argue it's the correct term. For collections that grow and shrink, it gets used for how much can be stored without a resize operation taking place internally; for a fixed size collection, though, there's no resizing possible. Here *capacity* still fits the same usage: it's how much fits in without needing an (impossible) resizing operation.

Comment: @chiastic-security - I have my opinion, you have yours.

Comment: That's the beauty of opinions :)